# Configure .net mvc with angular to use html 5 mode

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm developing an application in .net mvc with angularjs. When I don't use html5 mode it works fine, but when I set html5 mode to true the server calls that address giving me an he resource cannot be found.

This is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/test',
    {
        templateUrl: 'templates/TestPage.html',
        controller: 'ProfesionalController'
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


});
```

And this is my view (layout):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="~/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/home/home.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/profesional/profesional.js"></script>
<base href="/">
         <a href="test">Test</a>
         @*this is the link*@

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ng-app="myApp" class="container body-content">
    <div ng-view></div>
    @RenderBody()

</div>
```

When I click to test link the server try to locate: http://localhost:39881/test" giving me an 404 Not Found - http://localhost:39881/test"

What I'm missing. It works well with no html5 mode.

Comment: Post your controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc hosting angular app with html5mode and routing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730797/asp-net-mvc-hosting-angular-app-with-html5mode-and-routing)

Comment: The angular controller i'ts not big thing:
app.controller('ProfesionalController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.profesional= 'hi Customer!';


});

Comment: I meant your MVC controller.

Comment: The MVC controller it's the default index controller:
public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Customer/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }

Comment: I watched several tutorials and non of them configure anything to get html5 mode in .net mvc.

Answer (score 2):

In your mvc route config catch all url's and redirect to your index page. It will help.

```
   routes.MapRoute(
      name: "AngularCatchAll",
      url: "{*url}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: With a catchall, how do you route JSON posts/requests to the proper controller?

Comment: Configure mvc routing it's in case you hit refresh located in an angular route don't get a 404, because it will hit the server with an unknown url. If you use the links that's not necessary.

Comment: In this case I'm using WebAPI controllers to post/get data, with different routing. I'm dont use MVC Controllers at all. All routing and templating doing by Angular.

Comment: Worked for me (API calls were not affected). Only needed to replace url: with template: