# Angular Js Strange issue Ui Router Html5mode enabled page refresh issue in mvc 500 error

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-ui-router, iis-7.5

i have enabled the html5mode to remove Hashing from web url,after that i get an error.so i have mentioned the base href  in master page. set rewrite url in  web config.

when i goes into state view page and refresh the page it will show the wrong url.when launch the application in iis 7.5 getting error.

for that i have rewrite the url.

[image]

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="RewriteRules stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*"/>
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input ="{REQUEST_FILEName}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILEName}" matchType="IsDirectory"  negate="true"/>
<add input ="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true"/>
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="home/home"/>
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Can anyone helpme

Comment: for resolving that i have installed Iis url rewrite, after that i am not able to launch app i got another error.  check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349939/url-rewrite-issue-in-mvc-application-webconfig,

Answer (score 1):

when you enable html5mode, your all request should redirected to your main url (where your application start ex. home/index). try add below code in the RegisterRoutes method

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "Default1",
                  url: "{*.}",
                  defaults: new
                  {
                      controller = "Home",
                      action = "Index",
                  }
              );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Comment: so i  have don't need to rewrite the url in webconfig and  base href in layout ? mentioned the route config in enough.