# Angular 2 setup issue with asp.net core while using controller name and action name main.js not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

I have successfully setup my angular 2 application in asp.net core which is working great. **My main.js file is inside the app folder**.

Working fine beacause the default mvc templete is

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

[image: working fine template]

I am facing a new problem. I have use the achor tag as below. `

```
<li><a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Login </a></li>
```

Now the navigation URL is http://localhost:28739/Account/Login

In my systemjs.config.js I have mention the main as show below

```
 packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
```

Its works great when there is no controller name and action name in the url. But when their is controller name and action name. It gives me a error as main.js not found. Below is the image.

[image: error of main.js not found]

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this issue.

Comment: When it works fine, have you checked the network log? What is the endpoint hit for main.js?

Comment: @chandermani - I have updated . Please have a look. Please let me know how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: You should have url rewrite setup correctly for server to work with html5 mode, with hashless urls. See if this answer helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730797/asp-net-mvc-hosting-angular-app-with-html5mode-and-routing. Basically your server should always resolve to same route always when using Angular

Comment: No It is not working ....

Comment: Are you using Angular router or does clicking the link load the complete page? Also have you set `<base href='/'>` in the `<head>` section?

Comment: I am using asp.net core anchor tag for navigation. Please help me resolve this issue ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Found the solution. Here is the reference link http://blog.nbellocam.me/2016/03/21/routing-angular-2-asp-net-core/

I have added in startup.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    template: "{*url}",defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

And add `<Head><base href="/" /></Head>` in the layout view

Answer (score 0):

Use `<base href="/"  />` in your index page.