# Getting 404 error when Angular HTML5Mode is true

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router, html5-history, angular1.6

I have implemented pretty url in angular(switched to html5mode).

When I am refreshing the page I get 404 error.

For example: If I open my app using http://server/, everything works fine,but  when I refersh the page or try open specific page ex http://server/mypage, I get 404 error.

**Note:**

- When compiling my application I am combining templates in javascript.
- And after compilation my scripts(with template) goes in build folder
  and base tag in index.html is set to "/";.
- I am using Angular-ui-router.
- Using .net as backend.
- Frontend app is total separate from backend & both are deployed in IIS.

Please suggest what could be the possible solution or reason for the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are should to check your settings in backend, when i am using html5 history, i have for this my .htaccess file (where you redirect all your requests to your root index.php or index.html file), look my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On  
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

if this not help, you are can to read this [[article]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730797/asp-net-mvc-hosting-angular-app-with-html5mode-and-routing)